# Javascript: Comma operator, var, and scope - why does it work the way it does?

Tags: javascript, scope, operator-precedence

The comma operator evaluates each comma-separated operand (and returns the value of the last one).

```
(i = 1 + 2), (j = 3 + 4);
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
i = 1 + 2;
j = 3 + 4;
```

Also, as far as I know, a statement, such as var, is not considered an operator, but rather part of the operand.  (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence )

So if each operand is being separately evaluated, why, then, does

```
function foobar () {
    var i = 3, j = 7, z;
}
```

create 3 variables - i, j, and z - in foobar's scope?

I know that's what actually happens, but I've been wondering for a while why it is that this actually happens.  It would seem that i should be in foobar's scope, but that j and z should end up in the global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commas used in a `var` statement are not actually comma operators.

Similarly, the commas you use to separate arguments in a function call are not comma operators either.

Comment: Have any references on this claim?  I don't see it actually stated in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Ah, I do see it, though, in the example's text at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Comma_Operator .  I guess this is that tiny difference which makes it "*almost* the same", rather than "the same"...

Comment: Reference: a `var` statement has the comma [specified as its own syntax element](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement) (ECMAScript spec)